# HTML TextArea Limiting the amount of lines

Tags: html

I would like to have a textarea where users can enter a maximum of 255 digits and 5 lines of text. Then when they click on the "Post" button the text will be send to a different php file. 
The text gets sent to the second php file and the limit of 255 digits works (maxlength="255"), but I can't get the limit on lines. I googled it, searched the forum and tried multiple things, but nothing works. 
This is one of the things I tried.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
$('textarea[name=message]').on('keypress', function (event) {
var textarea = $(this),
    numberOfLines = (textarea.val().match(/\n/g) || []).length + 1,
    maxRows = 5;

if (event.which === 13 && numberOfLines === maxRows ) {
  return false;
}
});
});
</script>
<textarea name="message" placeholder="What's on your mind?" maxlength="255" data-limit-rows=true></textarea>

<input type="submit" value="Post">
</form>
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you limiting the number of carriage returns (times the user has hit enter) or the number of lines of text according to the width of the textarea?

Comment: @fauxserious I would like to limit the amount of lines of text. That code I copied from someone else. Because I thought it would do that.

Comment: ...According to textarea width?

Comment: @fauxserious the amount of lines. This is a number not a width.

Comment: But it can be affected by width. The number of lines you can fit in a width of 100px is different from the number of lines you can fit in 600px.

Comment: @fauxserious I understand that it can be affected by it. But why do you think I posted this? Stop asking me how to do it because if I knew that I wouldn't have posted this.

Comment: I'm not asking how to do it, I'm trying to get clarification to your question. This question can be interpreted in a few ways. I'll answer for you assuming you do not mean carriage returns...

Comment: I've asked this almost a month ago. I just want to limit the amount of lines a user can type.

Answer (score 0):

The number of lines of text in a container is normally dependent on the dimensions of that container. Therefore, you'll need some information about the text inside of the textarea first.

We can assume that one character is the height of one line in the textarea. This is of course also dependent on the font-size and font-family of the characters in the textarea. Once we get these dimensions, we can check to see how many lines have been typed in the textarea. Unfortunately, we'll need to replicate some of this using a div with the same width as the textarea in order to check these numbers.

```js
var textarea = document.getElementById('userinput');
var button = document.getElementById('checklines');

button.onclick = function(){
  var temp = document.createElement('div');
  temp.style.width = textarea.clientWidth + 'px';
  var style = window.getComputedStyle(textarea)
  temp.style.fontFamily = style.getPropertyValue("font-family");
  temp.style.fontSize = style.getPropertyValue("font-size");
  temp.textContent = 'X';
  document.body.appendChild(temp);
  var unit = temp.clientHeight; // height of one line
  temp.textContent = textarea.value;
  var lines = temp.clientHeight / unit;
  console.log(lines);
  temp.outerHTML = '';
}
```

```html
<textarea id="userinput"></textarea>
<button id="checklines">Check Lines</button>
```